# How do I retrieve all the vases from my Firebase Database?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I would simply like to retrieve all the data from my Products node I  am unsure how to do this, this is how my database is set up.

```
Producuts(yes I am aware products is misspelled) 
 sH8LzoaH9UaXahlmssixTpvQy8q2 (UUID)
 -LiToCix_BpBU2G5b0GF (Push value)
 Description: 
 PostImage: 
 -Lj71JBxtvmbjTRLaA-6  (Push value)
 Description: 
 PostImage: 
 -Lj71K5QfoguoLKdUDL4.  (Push value)
 Description:  
 PostImage:
```

As you can see from my code snippet I have already set a value event listener, I am unsure of how to retrieve all the values from the Products node.

```
public void fetchUserInfo(){

    productDatabaseRefrence = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Producuts").child(currentUser.getUid());
    productDatabaseRefrence.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            String mGroupId = productDatabaseRefrence.push().getKey();
            Log.i("id",mGroupId);


        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });

}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the image, you have the following database:

```
Producuts(yes I am aware products is misspelled) 
   sH8LzoaH9UaXahlmssixTpvQy8q2 (UUID)
      -LiToCix_BpBU2G5b0GF (Push value)
         Description: 
         PostImage: 
      -Lj71JBxtvmbjTRLaA-6  (Push value)
         Description: 
         PostImage: 
      -Lj71K5QfoguoLKdUDL4.  (Push value)
         Description:  
         PostImage:
```

To retrieve the `description` and `postimage` in your database, try the following:

```
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
   for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
      String key  = ds.getKey();
      String desc = ds.child("Description").getValue(String.class);
      String img  = ds.child("PostImage").getValue(String.class);
   }
}
```

Using `getKey()` you can retrieve the random id example `-LiToCix_BpBU2G5b0GF (Push value)` and using `child()` you can retrieve the different children under each random id.

Comment: Thanks for the response and it works. Do you know how I would go about retrieving all the information from inside the Producuts node?

Comment: This answer retrieves everything inside the Products node, add a `Log` and check